# Unable to return result when using AWS Lambda NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to implement a simple Node Js function on AWS Lambda to query data from dynamoDB. 
I hooked this lambda function to my API gateway, but I don't see any results when i access the API url.

```
//Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

// Create DynamoDB service object
var b = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var params = {
   ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#devicetimestamp": "timestamp"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':unitID': {S: 'arena-MXHGMYzBBP5F6jztnLUdCL'},
    ':dtimestamp' : {S: '1582920096000'}
   },
 KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :unitID and #devicetimestamp > :dtimestamp',
 TableName: 'IoTdata2'
};

b.query(params, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
});
```

Code works fine as i see the results from `console.log(JSON.stringify(results));`
when i use event handler

````
//Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

// Create DynamoDB service object
var b = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {

var params = {
   ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#devicetimestamp": "timestamp"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':unitID': {S: 'arena-MXHGMYzBBP5F6jztnLUdCL'},
    ':dtimestamp' : {S: '1582920096000'}
   },
 KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :unitID and #devicetimestamp > :dtimestamp',
 TableName: 'IoTdata2'
};

b.query(params, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        callback(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
       callback(null, results);
    }
});
};

```i don't see any response in API URL.I am new to nodeJS, Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks
````

Comment: post all of the relevant code, including the exports and you triggering the callback

Comment: @bryan60 Updated the post. I used to do the same export handler implementation to query data from mysql and it used to work fine. Thanks

Comment: all looks fine... can try putting your query callback in an arrow function to make sure callback is properly defined in the scope.  but shouldn't be needed here. how are you invoking

Comment: I have created an REST API get method from AWS api gateway and used this lambda function at the integration point. 
https://7gzx1fdgn5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/test this is the url
Thanks

Comment: can’t do much with a url. You have some debugging steps to follow. 1. Invoke your lambda directly and confirm it works as expected. If so, 2. Configure your gateway to respond with a dummy parameter and confirm that works as expected. If so, 3. Configure your lambda to just callback a dummy value and confirm that works as expected. Somewhere in there something will break. If they all work, then you’ve got a real mystery

Comment: also, i just remembered api gateway has a specific response structure from lambdathat it doesn't look like you're meeting: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html

Comment: Now i am able to see the response from both my console.log and callback(results), and now API url is giving me response as 'null'

Comment: Examples of how to respond using callbacks or async responses: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

Answer (score 3):

since you're going through API gateway, there's a specific response contract from lambda you need to meet, try doing it like this:

```
const response = {
  statusCode: 200, // need a status code
  body: JSON.stringify(results) // and a string body
}

callback(null, response)
```

a bit more info here: [TUTORIAL: Build a Hello World API with Lambda Proxy Integration - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)